# How do I get the add to homescreen banner on my site in Chrome like Flipkart?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, progressive-web-apps

I want to customize my website similar to www.flipkart.com(if loaded on chrome-android and click "add to home-screen"). On clicking on the icon created by this option, it shows a splash screen and doesn't shows the address bar. How can I achieve this behavior for my website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whilst one of the answers that highlights installtohomescreen is partially correct our full guidance is here:

- [Using App Install Banners](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/simplified-app-installs/?hl=en)

  - Create a manifest file including a short_name, icons and launch_url
  - Link to the manifest file from the page
- [Web App Install Banner](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/simplified-app-installs/web-app-install-banners?hl=en)

  - Optionally include extra information such as the `background_color` and `theme_color`.
- [Listening to events on App Install banner](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/simplified-app-installs/advanced?hl=en)

  - Learn when Chrome thinks it can prompt for install and then offer the ability to defer it until a more appropriate time.
  - Understand if the user has accepted or rejected the prompt by looking at the response in the `onbeforeinstallprompt` event.

Comment: Hi Kinlan, you should include essential details from the links to make this answer more stronger and explainable. Even link may no longer exist in the future! Read more about [providing context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) rule on FAQ

Comment: @kinlan what happens if user clicks x on add to homescreen. will the banner never appear again? Also, what happens if user does add to homescreen but then removes the homescreen icon, will the add to homescreen banner reappear?

Answer (score 0):

Finally Found a solution. Adding a manifest file does the job. Complete documentation here:

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen